# Visual Studio Pre/Post Build Event - Copy files to Directory in setup project

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project, post-build-event, pre-build-event

i have one folder in setup project called "SSRS_Repor". now i want that when i will create setup for my project then i want to copy all files from a folder exist in my project called "report" to folder SSRS_Repor exist in setup project. please guide me how can i do it. i know this can be done like writing script for setup Pre/Post Build Event but not aware properly.
i got a sample like

```
copy /Y "$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).dll" "$(SolutionDir)lib\$(ProjectName).dll"
```

but not clear where to set it.

it will be helpful if some one tell me all the steps in detail. thanks

Comment: if your problem is "where" the setting is, @jihlim answered it, please accept his solution.  If your problem is something else, please articulate.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on your project on Solution Explorer which you can find on the right, and click on "Properties".

Then go to "Build Events" under "Configuration Properties" in the tree, and expand it. You should see "Pre-Build event"/"Pre-Link Event"/"Post-Build Event".